# HTTP Server Using Lua/ Torch7

Tags: api, http, lua, torch

I'm starting to learn Torch7 to get into the machine learning/ deep learning field and I'm finding it fascinating (and very complicated haha). My main concern, however, is if I can turn this learning into an application - mainly can I turn my Torch7 Lua scripts into a server that an app can use to perform machine learning calculations? And if it's possible, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at Torch as a library (even though you may be accessing it as a standalone executable). That library can be used from some Lua code that is accessible through HTTP. The Lua code may be running inside [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/), which would take care of all HTTP interactions, and you get the same performance as OpenResty can be configured to use LuaJIT.

Another option is to use HTTP processing based on luasocket and copas libraries (for examples, [Xavante](http://keplerproject.github.io/xavante/)) or use one of the options listed on [LuaWebserver](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaWebserver) page.

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have a recommendation as to which method we should use? We're thinking use case would be image classification, text summarization and data mining for enterprise. So far thoughts are AWS server with a GPU, running Torch7 as a server.

Comment: I think the most versatile way will be to continue running torch as a server that can communicate over TCP (possibly using async package @smhx references) with another component running on the same machine that handles HTTP interactions. This way you can use and test your code independently of HTTP and integrate in various ways without affecting your core implementation. The main challenge is going to be in figuring out good API to use over sockets.

Comment: Why would you recommend TCP instead of using async's JSON implementation? Also, what do you mean by, "figuring out good API to use over sockets"? I'm thinking nodejs might be able to do this well if that's what you mean

Answer (score 5):

You can use [waffle](https://github.com/benglard/waffle). Here's the hello world example on it's page:

```
local app = require('waffle')

app.get('/', function(req, res)
   res.send('Hello World!')
end)

app.listen()
```

lets say your algorithm is a simple face detector. The input is an image and the output is the face detections in some json format. You can do the following:

```
local app = require('waffle')
require 'graphicsmagick'
require 'MyAlgorithm'

app.post('/', function(req, res)
  local img, detections, outputJson
  img = req.form.image_file:toImage()
  detections = MyAlgorithm.detect(img:double())
  outputJson = {}
  if (detections ~= nil) then
    outputJson.faceInPicture = true
    outputJson.faceDetections = detections
  else
    outputJson.faceInPicture = false
    outputJson.faceDetections = nil
  end
  res.json(outputJson)
end)

app.listen()
```

That way your algorithm can be used as an independent service.

Comment: This works when you already have a trained model. How would you add an image and train your model ? Like, http post request sends an image, that image must be processed into training set and then training happens and finally the model updates. Have you any examples to do the same ?

Comment: It seems, "waffle" is not accepting the parallel http requests. What I need to do to accept parallel requests?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [async](https://github.com/clementfarabet/async) package that we've tested with torch.

Comment: It seems, "async" too not accepting the parallel http requests. What I want to do to accept parallel requests?

Answer (score 1):

Both [async](https://github.com/clementfarabet/async) and [waffle](https://github.com/benglard/waffle) are great options. Another option is to use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:lua) + [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/djungelorm/protobuf-lua). Whatever your preferred web development environment is, you can send requests to Torch using ZeroMQ in asynchronous manner, possibly serializing messages with protocol buffers, then process each request in Torch and return the result back.

This way I managed to get much higher throughput, than [waffle](https://github.com/benglard/waffle)'s 20K fib test.

Answer (score 0):

Try llserver - minimalistic Lua server. Runs as single coroutine, serves dynamic content via callback function: https://github.com/ncp1402/llserver
You can perform other tasks/calculations in additional coroutines.